# Mismatched Token Exception Hive Query

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, pyspark, hiveql

I have a single delimited string created by this python/spark function:

```
singleStringOfDelimitedNames= '|'.join([str(x.asDict().values()[0])  for x in
df3.collect()])
```

Let's say it says 'Dan|Susie Ann|Bob.'
When I pass this String into this Hive UDF I created,

```
df2 = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT field1, field2
                     FROM
                     refinedTable
                     WHERE
                     createdHiveUDF({0}, {1}, cast(field1 as string), cast(field2 as string))
                     """.format(percentage, singleStringOfDelimitedNames))
```

I'm getting a Mismatched Token Exception (26!=301). u"mismatched input 'Ann' expecting ) near 'Susie' in function specification.

What confuses me is when I hardcode "Dan|Susie Ann|Bob," shown below, everything is working as I intended.

```
df2 = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT field1, field2
                     FROM
                     refinedTable
                     WHERE
                     createdHiveUDF({0}, 'Dan|Susie Ann|Bob', cast(field1 as string), cast(field2 as string))
                     """.format(percentage))
```

I'm assuming I'm either using .format incorrectly, or I have to find a different python/spark function to create a single delimited string from a column of names.  If anyone could help me understand this Mismatched Token Exception, and why the hard coding above avoids this issue, I would appreciate it.

Comment: didn't test anything on my side, but i recently used explode by | and it did't give me much luck - i tried exploding text based on | and it only gave me one character. only after escaping it with \\ did i get what i need. i guess reading the manual might have helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you missing single quotes?

```
df2 = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT field1, field2
                     FROM
                     refinedTable
                     WHERE
                     createdHiveUDF({0}, '{1}', cast(field1 as string), cast(field2 as string))
                     """.format(percentage, singleStringOfDelimitedNames))
```

Comment: It really was that simple huh.  Thank you Marie!